# Date Sorting in Java

Tags: java, sorting, collections

The Instruction was to create a Random dates for each object withn the range specified in the instructions below for the interview slot objects to be stored in . I am not exactly sure how to do this

Create a random number of  InterviewSlot objects and store them in the slots container.
Use the Math.random() method to create variation in the objects created:

- Make the range of variation of the dates in hours.
- The range should be 30 days, meaning that the dates could vary between
  say, today and 30 days from now. The max of the range would be equal
  to 30*24.
- You can set the minimum of the range to 1.
- Make the duration vary between 1 and 60.

Examples of objects:

```
Thu Apr 02 05:28:59 EDT 2020 duration:18
Fri Mar 27 00:22:32 EDT 2020 duration:48
Wed Apr 01 20:22:32 EDT 2020 duration:8
Sat Mar 28 19:22:32 EDT 2020 duration:31
```

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;







public class InterviewSlot implements Comparable<InterviewSlot> {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    private Date startTime = cal.getTime();
    private Integer duration;

    public InterviewSlot(Date start, Integer d) {
        setDuration(d);
        setStartTime(start);

    }

    public void setDuration(Integer duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public void setStartTime(Date startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }

    public Integer getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public Date getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "Interview Start " + getStartTime() + "Duration :  " + getDuration();
    }

    @Override

    public int compareTo(InterviewSlot s) {
        return this.getStartTime().compareTo(s.getStartTime());
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}


import java.awt.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DataCreator {

    public static <E extends Comparable<E>> void outputData(ArrayList<E> l) {
        for (E L : l) {
            System.out.println(L);
        }

    }

    public static void createIntegers(ArrayList<Integer> a, int num) {
        // double random = (int)(Math.random()*((100-1)+1))+1;
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            Integer random = (int) (Math.random() * ((100 - 1) + 1)) + 1;
            a.add(random);

        }

        ;
    }

    public static void createData(ArrayList<InterviewSlot> slots, int num) {

    }

}
```

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: I highly recommend you to use [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) that is the *new* Java API for handling dates and times. It is much more robust and nicer to use than the old classes, such as `Date` and `Calendar`.

Comment: @ScaryWombat How I can use the Random Generator to generate values between 1 and 30 days for my dates as implied in the instructions

Answer (score 3):

I will answer as if this is for real work, as you did not indicate explicitly schoolwork.

## `ThreadLocalRandom`

Use [`ThreadLocalRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) to avoid any possible concurrency issues. There is no downside to using this class over [`Math.random`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#random()). And this class has convenient methods for generating various types of numbers rather than just `double`.

## *java.time*

Never use `Calendar` or `Date`. Those terrible date-time classes were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Get today's date.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

Add random number of days within next 30 days.

```
int days = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( 1 , 31 ) ;
LocalDate localDate = today.plusDays( days ) ;
```

Days vary in length, such as 23, 24, 25, or other number of hours. So for your date in your zone, calculate maximum number of seconds.

```
ZonedDateTime start = localDate.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
ZonedDateTime stop = localDate.plusDays( 1 ).atStartOfDay( z ) ;
Duration d = Duration.between( start.toInstant() , stop.toInstant() ) ;
long seconds = d.toSeconds() ;  // In Java 9 and later. For Java 8, call `Duration::getSeconds`.
```

That count of seconds becomes the maximum for our length of day. From this we pick a random number of seconds.

```
long secondsIntoDay = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( 0 , seconds ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = start.plusSeconds( secondsIntoDay ) ;
```

Determine a random duration from 1 to 60 minutes for the elapsed time of each event.

```
int minutes = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( 1 , 61 ) ; // At least one minute, and less than 61 minutes.
Duration duration = Duration.ofMinutes( minutes ) ;
```

Define your `public class InterviewSlot` with two member fields: a `ZonedDateTime` and a `Duration`.

Comment: Excellent code , the only issue that I found when I tried out your code is that in Class `Duration` the method `toSeconds()` is private. I had to convert it after getting nano seconds.

Comment: @Ananthapadmanabhan The Javadoc for [`Duration::toSeconds`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#toSeconds()) says `public`. But that method was added in Java 9. If in Java 8 specifically, call the getter, `Duration::getSeconds`. That method is a getter because internally a `Duration` stores a pair of 64-bit long integers. One number is a count of whole seconds, the other a count of nanoseconds as the fraction of a second. I added a comment to the line of code in the Answer. Thanks for raising the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution with date for your spezific case, including an example:

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils;

```
public class SimpleDateGenerator {
    private static Random random = new Random();

    public static Date getRandomDate(Date start, long timerangeSeconds) {
        int randomTime = (int) Math.ceil(random.nextDouble() * timerangeSeconds);
        return DateUtils.addSeconds((Date) start.clone(), randomTime);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date now = new Date();
        System.out.println(now);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(getRandomDate(now, 30 * 24 * 60 * 60));
        }

    }

}
```

main gives following (example) output:

```
Tue Mar 31 08:26:14 CEST 2020
Sun Apr 19 16:06:48 CEST 2020
Fri Apr 03 20:49:58 CEST 2020
Wed Apr 22 22:27:00 CEST 2020
Mon Apr 06 03:39:48 CEST 2020
Wed Apr 22 19:13:28 CEST 2020
Fri Apr 03 12:36:16 CEST 2020
Wed Apr 22 20:27:35 CEST 2020
Mon Apr 06 13:58:37 CEST 2020
Fri Apr 03 03:57:17 CEST 2020
Wed Apr 15 09:05:47 CEST 2020
```

Answer (score 1):

As per @Basil Bourque suggestion the following code should do the trick :

```
import java.time.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numberOfRandomDates = 10;
    ArrayList<InterviewSlot>  interviewSlotArrayList= new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i< numberOfRandomDates ; i++) {
        InterviewSlot interviewSlot = calculateInterviewSlot();
        interviewSlotArrayList.add(interviewSlot);
        System.out.println(interviewSlot);
    }

    Collections.sort(interviewSlotArrayList);
    System.out.println("After sorting: \n");

    //Using lamda
    interviewSlotArrayList.forEach(element -> {
        System.out.println(element);
    });

    //or Using method reference
    interviewSlotArrayList.forEach(System.out::println);
  }

    public static InterviewSlot calculateInterviewSlot() {
        //Getting time zone id and setting local time according to the time zone
        ZoneId z = ZoneId.of("America/Montreal");
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(z);

        //Getting a random day between 1 and 31 and adding it to the current date
        int days = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 31);
        LocalDate localDate = today.plusDays(days);

        //Getting start and end time of the day as per time zone.End time is taken as next day start time(24 hr)
        ZonedDateTime start = localDate.atStartOfDay(z);
        ZonedDateTime stop = localDate.plusDays(1).atStartOfDay(z);

        //Duration is taken which is the max duration for that time zone.
        Duration duration = Duration.between(start.toInstant(), stop.toInstant());
        long seconds = TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(duration.toNanos(), TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);

        //Calculating random no of seconds keeping the computed seconds as max seconds in the day
        long secondsIntoDay = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, Math.toIntExact(seconds));
        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = start.plusSeconds(secondsIntoDay);

        //Calculating random no of minutes for duration
        int minutes = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 61);
        Duration durationMinutes = Duration.ofMinutes(minutes);

        return new InterviewSlot(zonedDateTime, durationMinutes);
    }
}
```

**InterviewSlot.java** :

```
public class InterviewSlot implements Comparable<InterviewSlot> {

    private ZonedDateTime startTime;
    private Duration duration;

    public InterviewSlot() {
    }

    public InterviewSlot(ZonedDateTime startTime, Duration duration) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public ZonedDateTime getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public void setStartTime(ZonedDateTime startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }

    public Duration getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(Duration duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "Interview Start " + getStartTime() + " Duration :  " + getDuration();
    }

    @Override

    public int compareTo(InterviewSlot s) {
        return this.getStartTime().compareTo(s.getStartTime());
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Generated sample output :

```
Interview Start 2020-04-24T02:16:09-04:00[America/Montreal] Duration :  PT12M
Interview Start 2020-04-04T20:58:43-04:00[America/Montreal] Duration :  PT38M
Interview Start 2020-04-25T00:09:12-04:00[America/Montreal] Duration :  PT31M
Interview Start 2020-04-03T20:26:01-04:00[America/Montreal] Duration :  PT22M
Interview Start 2020-04-06T03:48:29-04:00[America/Montreal] Duration :  PT45M
Interview Start 2020-04-15T07:56:32-04:00[America/Montreal] Duration :  PT34M
Interview Start 2020-04-21T09:25:15-04:00[America/Montreal] Duration :  PT44M
Interview Start 2020-04-30T18:33:40-04:00[America/Montreal] Duration :  PT52M
Interview Start 2020-04-16T07:12:54-04:00[America/Montreal] Duration :  PT14M
Interview Start 2020-04-24T17:02:48-04:00[America/Montreal] Duration :  PT50M
```